# Difference between "Reveal view controller set controller" and "Reveal view controller set segue"

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I've been working on SWrevealview controllers for slide out menu. While connecting a VC to a Navigation controller I see an option "reveal view controller set controller" whereas i've been familiar to "reveal view controller set segue" i've searched alot on about this but couldn't get to a solution. Can somebody tell me what is the difference between these two?